# Unable to Access Apache NiFi Rest API on local Windows 10 Machine

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I am using Apache NiFi 1.18, and my NiFi UI works perfectly on url http://localhost:9443/nifi/.

The moment I try to access NiFi API using http://localhost:8443/nifi-api/ using POSTMAN,, this error comes up.

Is this some sort of setup issue or installation issue please help me fix it, need NiFi API's for some backend coding

Tried to access NiFi API using URLs available in documentation, but failed [image]

Above is the issue which comes up on sending get request in postman

Comment: It might be a postman issue. Try copying the code (use the "code" link in postman) and running curl statement on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the same port you use for the UI. From my experience they should be the same.

Comment: It is the same port, I am unable to access the instance of local machine, but the deployed  variant works as expected, hence the doubt